# errors with subsample 0.0.6 in python2.6

Tags: python, linux, subsampling

I am trying to run the subsample0.0.6 package in python2.6.6 (to be able to run something like "> subsample -n 1000 big_data.csv" in python)

after installing subsample it seems to work at first after I check with "import subsample", but then when I move to a different directory and attempt to run the command, I get an error. Can anyone tell what is going on, or what I should do from here?

```
[sbsuser@localhost ~]$ python2.6
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Nov 21 2013, 10:50:32)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subsample
>>> help(subsample)
>>> import numpy
>>> import HTSeq
>>> quit()
[sbsuser@localhost ~]$ cd /illumina/runs/
[sbsuser@localhost runs]$ python2.6 subsample -n 1000 deseq.csv > s_des.csv
python2.6: can't open file 'subsample': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[sbsuser@localhost runs]$ python2.6 subsample.py -n 1000 deseq.csv >       s_des.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "subsample.py", line 4, in <module>
    fraction = float( sys.argv[1] )
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): -n
[sbsuser@localhost runs]$ python2.6
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Nov 21 2013, 10:50:32)
```

[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import subsample
> > >           Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >             File "", line 1, in 
> > >             File "subsample.py", line 4, in 
> > >               fraction = float( sys.argv[1] )
> > >           IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 2):

The [package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/subsample/0.0.6) has its own executable named `subsample` so you need to call your command as follows:

```
$ subsample -n 1000 deseq.csv > s_des.csv
```